# Why my Brushless motor Motor code is depended on another code in raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, python, raspberry-pi-os

I am very new to raspberry pi and hardware. I want to run a brushless (A2212/15 T 930Kv) Motor with ESC (Electronic Speed Control 30A). I found a code which runs my ESC and motor through loops. Then i modified that code to my own code, when i run my the code, the motor is working perfectly.

But the problem is when I turn off and then On the power of ESC, and try to run my own code, the motor beeps contentiously for 2 to 3 seconds and then nothing happens, but when I run the loops code, the motor runs perfectly. After running the loops code, my own code works perfectly. I don't know why. Please help. Below are the codes.

**My Own Code:**

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)

t1 = GPIO.PWM(7, 50)

t1.start(0)

t1.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
time.sleep(3)

t1.stop()

GPIO.cleanup()
quit()
```

**Loops Code:**

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(12, 50)

p.start(0)
print ("starting 0")
time.sleep(3)

p.ChangeDutyCycle(3)
print("start")
time.sleep(5)



while True:
    i = 4
    while i<10:
        
        print(i)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(.05)
        i +=.02
    
    while i>4:
        print(i)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(.05)
        i -=.05
```

Comment: Perhaps the ESC is being initialised by the loops code?

Comment: is there any other way to initialise the ESC?

Comment: you make it sound like `loops` is a library  ... what exactly do you mean by Loops